# IF EXISTS ELSE?

Tags: mysql

How would one fix this query?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM links WHERE age='10')

SELECT * FROM links WHERE age = '10' ORDER BY

ELSE

SELECT * FROM links ORDER BY
```

So if a link exists which is 10 days exactly then it would be displayed otherwise it would be random.

Comment: You say "if *a* link exists, then *it* would..." which implies that you are going to be fetching just one row. Did you need ALL the rows with `age='10'`?

Answer (score 1):

You have two different queries - use a union:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM links
 WHERE age = '10'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT *
 FROM links
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM links WHERE age='10')
 ORDER BT RAND()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could write:

```
SELECT *
  FROM links
 WHERE age = '10'
    OR NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT 1
            FROM links
           WHERE age = '10'
        )
 ORDER
    BY RAND()
 LIMIT 1
;
```

. . . but I'm not sure how well it will perform. It *may* make more sense to just run the query with `WHERE age = '10'`, and then run the other query only if the first returns no results.

Comment: This query doesn't give a random link if a link with age 10 does not exist?

Comment: @user2700729: This will return all rows with `age = '10'`, if any exist; otherwise, it will return all rows. Are you saying that instead of returning *all* rows, it should only return *one* row? And by "random" do you just mean that you don't care which row it returns, or are you saying that you actually want randomness?

Comment: there will always be 1 entry only with a specific age. So i want like this :) IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM links WHERE age='10')

SELECT * FROM links WHERE age = '10' ORDER BY RANDOM

ELSE

SELECT * FROM links ORDER BY RANDOM

Comment: @user2700729: `ORDER BY RANDOM` doesn't affect the number of rows returned, it just returns them in a random order. Is that what you want?

Comment: The first thing will always return one row only, and in the second one you can add limit 0,1 I believe? I'm really new to mysql. Basically I just want "DO THIS, IF THIS DOESN'T WORK THEN DO THIS" to work :P

Comment: @user2700729: SQL queries don't "do" things; they're not procedural. I've updated my answer with what I think you want.